# triplestore or graph database more suitable for this application?

Tags: neo4j, rdf, wikidata, virtuoso, triplestore

I am trying build a domain specific question answering system using the Wikidata that already has the rdf/json dump format.

There are pros and cons between triplestore (e.g. virtuoso) and graph (e.g. neo4j), I made a lot of reading but still can't decide which.

People said triplestore is good for inferencing/reasoning, while graph is not but I thought with graph in neo4j we can write Cypher in such a way that can do inferencing too [such as this](https://towardsdatascience.com/inference-in-graph-database-7203938932a0) , so what I am not aware of ? Is it easier to query with SPARQL than Cypher for inferencing ?

I am leaning towards using graph database as it has a couple of advantages as [explained here](https://neo4j.com/blog/rdf-triple-store-vs-labeled-property-graph-difference/) but maybe it has bias because it's written by neo4j. But if I choose this route, means I have to sanitize a lot of rdf data when importing to neo4j with the neosemantic plugin ?! I am not sure how direct it's and if it will be painful to import them.

I would prefer to have everything stored in a single db that include the user's login system, application specific data as well.

so what is more suitable in my situation, triplestore or graph ? Thanks

Comment: It simply depends on the types of queries you need. If you need graph traversal, mostly cypher will be better suited. But,  you know how large wikidata is? Also, what kind of question answering are you doing. There are already plenty of approaches. What does your system do better than state of the art?

Comment: Anyways, good luck loading wikidata. I know from people that it can take a few days. I'm happy to hear about some stats when you loaded it into neo4j

Comment: @UninformedUser yes I know how big it's, that's why I said "domain specific", so I will be using a subset of the data only e.g. geography / disease , I have downloaded the dump which is 55GB when compressed in bz2 ! It will be a web natural language question answering. I want to be able to handle question that goes 1 - 3 level deep just an example "What are the countries that has the leader who has no children". I need to figure out a little more about graph traversal, my initial thought is for now I won't need but i want it as a provision too.

Comment: @UninformedUser Although I won't need the cutting edge tech for now but if I want to start something I want to start with the best foundation so there will be less pain for redoing everything again.

Comment: Tradeoffs… Take a look at [Tabulated Comparison of Relational Database Management Systems (RDBMS)](https://community.openlinksw.com/t/274) and [Neo4J vs Virtuoso on DB-Engines](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Neo4j%3BVirtuoso). Note that Virtuoso is more than a triple store; it's a hybrid DBMS, handling RDF (both triples and quads), SQL, XML, plain-text, and other data structures (and related query languages). Also, Virtuoso supports reasoning/inference via numerous interaction interfaces including, for example, [Jena and/or RDF4J/Sesame](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/46d0ce5e8fec).

Comment: @William you also have consider then the different types of models, RDF vs property graph. There is a big difference - also this comes into account when you use the Wikidata dump as Wikidata model has a lots of information attach via statements about statements. This is definitely not something the Neo4J Importer will take into account for sure as it is Wikidata specific. I'm telling you this because when youäre doing question answering, and I basically know all the approaches, you'll end up with subgraph retrieval and/or graph traversal. Like give me the smallest subgraph containing all nodes